# Converting NSString to key value pair

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary, key-value, keyvaluepair

I have a response from server which is NSString and looks like this

```
resp=handshake&clientid=47D3B27C048031D1&success=true&version=1.0
```

I want to convert it to key value pair , something like dictionary or in an array .
I couldn't find any useful built-in function for decoding the NSString to NSdictionary and replacing the & with space didn't solve my problem , can anyone give me any idea or is there any function for this problem ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work (off the top of my head):

```
NSMutableDictionary *pairs = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSString *pairString in [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"]) {
    NSArray *pair = [pairString componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];

    if ([pair count] != 2)
        continue;

    [pairs setObject:[pair objectAtIndex:1] forKey:[pair objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

or you could use an `NSScanner`, though for something as short as a query string the extra couple of arrays won't make a performance difference.